# Display all posts ordered by date

Tags: php, wordpress

By default WordPress homepage shows latest posts. How can I display the latest posts on a page that is not the homepage ?

My first goal "GOAL A" is for the homepage to display a specific category called "popular posts" (instead of latest posts).
"GOAL B" is to have a link on the menu to ALL posts ordered by date, aka "the latest posts".

I have accomplished GOAL A with code below. How can I accomplish "GOAL B" ? I can make a category called "New" and make that a link on the menu, but how can I make it display all posts ordered by date ? Or is there a better method ?

.
**"GOAL A" CODE: display specific category on homepage**

```
function popular_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'popular' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'popular_category' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best here will be is to create a static front page with a blog page. This seems to be fit for what you are trying to do

## Here is how:

**STEP 1**

You should delete the code in your question. This will not be necessary here

**STEP 2**

Make a copy of your `page.php` (or `index.php`) and rename it `front-page.php`. Open it up, and replace the loop with a custom query which will only display posts from the desired category. Unfortunately, `pre_get_posts` does not work on a static front page, so here you will have to make use of a custom query.

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=popular&posts_per_page=10&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Just remember, for paging on a static front page, you have to use `page`, not `paged` as you would for all other custom queries.*

**STEP 3**

Make a copy of your `index.php` and rename it `home.php`. This will be your blog page template

**STEP 4**

You can now set your static front page and blog page in the back. You should have a read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) about setting up a static front page and a blog page